Detect if sidepanel is open in Chrome extension
I'm making a Chrome extension. I need to respond to when the sidepanel is closed. The following code seems to work:
Background script:
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function (port) {
  const id = port.name.split("__")[1];
  if (!id) return;
  const tabId = parseInt(id);

  // Connect to sidepanel when open
  if (port.name.startsWith(SIDEPANEL_MSG_NAME)) {
    // Detect when sidepanel is closed
    port.onDisconnect.addListener(async () => {
      doSomethingWhenSidePanelIsClosed({ tabId });
    });
  }
});

In sidepanel:
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!tabId) return;

    // Create connection so that the background script can know when the sidepanel is closed
    const port = chrome.runtime.connect({
      name: `${SIDEPANEL_MSG_NAME}__${tabId}`
    });

    // Cleanup function
    return () => {
      port.disconnect();
    };
  }, [tabId]);

However Ive read that the port messaging is not 100% reliable and it's a good idea to "ping" the sidepanel periodically to check if its open.
Background script:
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function (port) {
  const id = port.name.split("__")[1];
  if (!id) return;
  const tabId = parseInt(id);

  // Connect to sidepanel when open
  if (port.name.startsWith(SIDEPANEL_MSG_NAME)) {
    // Detect when sidepanel is closed
    port.onDisconnect.addListener(async () => {
      doSomethingWhenSidePanelIsClosed({ tabId });
    });
  }

  setInterval(async () => {
      try {
        await chrome.runtime.sendMessage(`sidepanel_ping__${tabId}`, (res) => {
          if (res === "sidepanel_pong") {
            console.log("sidepanel open");
            return;
          }
          console.log("sidepanel closed");
          doSomethingWhenSidePanelIsClosed({ tabId });
        });
      } catch () {
      }
  }, 1000);
});

Sidepanel:
  useEffect(() => {
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, _sender, sendResponse) => {
      if (message === `sidepanel_ping__${tabId}`) {
        sendResponse("sidepanel_pong");
      }
    });
  }, []);

This works when the sidepanel is open but errors when it's closed, and the console.log("sidepanel closed"); never runs. I tried adding a try / catch block but it has no effect.
There is a similar question here but the comments under the accepted answer say that it doesnt always work: Is there a way to detect if the chrome SidePanel is open?
There is another similar question but it doesn't handle pinging, so I imagine it has the same issue as the previous question? Detect in content script when sidePanel is opened or closed?

Port messaging is 100% reliable, so just use it.

@woxxom the official documentation for the DevTools say to "Send a periodic heartbeat to keep the port open". Do DevTools behave differently to the Sidepanel?
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/how-to/devtools/extend-devtools#detecting-open-close

No, the heartbeat is necessary to keep the service worker (the background script) alive, which would die otherwise in 30 seconds. The documentation is maintained mostly by people who have no experience in extension development, so they occasionally provide incorrect explanations.
